# Can't register on site using webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browser-automation

For training purposes trying to test registering using Selenium WebDriver. Manually could do this and navigating to profile page, but using WebDriver after submitting username/email and password I stay on the same page not logging. Though registration is perfromed successfully as I could log in using specified credentials.

Manual scenario:

1. Navigate to `https://hdrezka.ag/`
2. Click register button to open register pop-up
   `register_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.b-tophead__register')`
3. Fill in email, login, password fields.
4. Click register_submit_button:
   `register_submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@name='submit']")`
5. If you do it manually element profile_dropdown will be displayed. If do it using script (I set breakpoint to try clicking register_submit_button manually as well), element profile_dropdown will not be displayed.
   `profile_dropdown = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located ((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='b-tophead-dropdown'] [text()='Профиль']")))`

I tried:

- incognito mode
- disable-blink-features
- disabling extensions
- setting user agent

Maybe you have some other ideas?

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

path = r''  # TODO: specify path to webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={userAgent}')


driver = Chrome(service=Service(path), chrome_options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://hdrezka.ag/')

agent = driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent;')
print(agent)

register_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.b-tophead__register')
register_button.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
register_popup = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'register-popup')))

time.sleep(5)

from random import randint
valid_register_login = f"user{randint(1, 100000000000)}"
valid_register_email = f"{valid_register_login}@test.com"
valid_register_password = ''.join([chr(randint(48, 57)) + chr(randint(65, 90)) + chr(randint(97, 122)) for _ in range(5)])
print()
print(f"login: {valid_register_login}")
print(f"email: {valid_register_email}")
print(f"password: {valid_register_password}")

input_register_email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
input_register_email.send_keys(valid_register_email)
email_validity_checker = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#result-registration-email span.string-ok')))
assert email_validity_checker.is_displayed()

input_register_login = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'name')
input_register_login.send_keys(valid_register_login)
login_validity_checker = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#result-registration-login span.string-ok')))
assert login_validity_checker.is_displayed()

input_register_password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password1')
input_register_password.send_keys(valid_register_password)

register_submit_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@name='submit']")
register_submit_button.click()

# Failed here as page is not updated when using script
profile_dropdown = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located ((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='b-tophead-dropdown'] [text()='Профиль']")))
assert profile_dropdown.is_displayed()

driver.quit()
```

Expected element after successful registration:
[image]

Comment: At which line are you stuck exactly?

Comment: It last block. Webdriver can't find element profile_dropdown, because doesn't perform navigation after clicking register_submit_button
profile_dropdown = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located ((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='b-tophead-dropdown'] [text()='Профиль']")))

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element you are trying to identify through `By.XPATH, "//span[@class='b-tophead-dropdown'] [text()='Профиль']")`

Comment: Which element is `//span[@class='b-tophead-dropdown'] [text()='Профиль']")`? Seems we can't login unless we login.

Comment: I added screenshot with expected element. The problem is that during manual registration login is included, but during automated registration, new user is registered (you could login suing his credentials) but expected login is not perfromed.